# React Router v4: custom PrivateRoute component keeps reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router, react-router-v4

this is my first ever question so please spare my life.

I tried doing all the research I could and I've given up.

so basically I'm dealing with protected routes with react-router v4. After looking at Tyler Mcginnis' PrivateRoute, I thought I was on the right track but nope.

I can correctly set `isAuthenticated: true` with the `requireUser` function, but the PrivateRoute route component never renders. It always redirects to `/login`. After further investigation, I realized that somehow the page refreshes and therefore sets `isAuthenticated` back to `false`

also, I'm not using Redux.

OH, and any critics to my code is welcomed.

pls help

**/App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
      user: {
        username: ''
      }
    }
  }
  requireUser = (userData) => {
    console.log('userData', userData);
    if(userData) {
      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: {
          username: userData.username
        }
      })
    }
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />

          <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
          <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
          <Route path='/login' render={(props) => {
            return <Login {...props} requireUser={this.requireUser} />
          }} />
          <PrivateRoute path='/search' component={SearchBar} auth={this.state.isAuthenticated} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**/PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, path, ...rest}) => {
  return <Route {...rest} path='/search'  render={(props) => {
    console.log(auth);
    if(auth) {
      return (
        <Component {...props} />
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Redirect to='/login' />
      )
    }
  }} />
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

**EDIT: added in my Login component**

**UPDATE: I ended up adding `this.props.history.push('/search)` to my `handleOnSubmit` function**

**/Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    }
  }

  handleOnChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    // prevent page refresh
    e.preventDefault()
    // destructure state
    const { email, password } = this.state
    // assign to userData
    const userData = { email, password }
    // axios post /api/users/login
    axios
      .post('/api/users/login', userData)
      .then((response) => {
        // destructure
        const { token } = response.data
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
        this.props.requireUser(decoded)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="section">
        <div className="container">
          <form>
            <div className="field">
              <label className="label">Email</label>
                <div className="control">
                  <input 
                      type="email" 
                      placeholder="email"   
                      className="input" 
                      name='email'
                      onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                  />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label className="label">Password</label>
              <input 
                type="password" 
                placeholder="password" 
                className="input" 
                name='password'
                onChange={this.handleOnChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <div className="control">
                <button 
                  onClick={this.handleOnSubmit}
                  type="submit" 
                  className="button is-primary"
                >Log In</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default Login
```

Comment: What does your `Login` component look like? Is that something you have written yourself?

Comment: @Tholle sorry I should've added that component. Just edited it in!

Comment: You say that "somehow the page refreshes and therefore ...". Are you writing `/search` in the address bar, or are you pressing on a React Router `Link` component?

Comment: @Tholle yup, `token` is set in the response. `jwt_decode(token)` returns the correct info

Comment: @Tholle you are correct, i am typing into the address bar...in retrospect i guess that makes sense why it refreshes.

I'm trying to have it redirect to `/search` when `isAuthenticated:true`

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, you're right. Changing the URL in the address bar will always result in a refresh. There is no way around that. I think if you try a `<Link to="/search">Search</Link>` component, your code will work fine.

Comment: @Tholle ah yes I haven't tried adding a `Link` component. I tried and it works. I guess I have to find another way to somehow `history.push('/search')`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! You're welcome. If you want to `push` in a component that is used as the `component` prop for a `Route`, you can write `this.props.history.push('/search');`

Comment: @Tholle Thanks! Everything works now

I ended up wrapping my `Login` component with `withRouter` and then added `this.props.history.push('/search')` after the axios request!

Comment: Awesome! I don't think you need `withRouter`, since you are giving `Login` the route props already. `<Login {...props} requireUser={this.requireUser} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code looks sound. The issue is that when you manually change the address bar to `/search`, the browser will be refreshed. There is no way around that.

You could alternatively use a [`Link`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) component with a `to` prop value of `'/search'` that your user can use to navigate to the search, or you could programmatically change the path with the `history` object.

```
this.props.history.push('/search');
```